# Vsfp user don't see any data linux Rhel/Centos

Tags: linux, centos, rhel, vsftpd

I tried creating vsftp server on Rhel 8 and centos. My ftp Users can login into server but only sed list of directory's and are able to navigate to any directory.

User cannot create directory or file
User cannot see any files in any directory.

I chnage chmod  777 
And changed ownership but nothing works

Comment: Stack Overflow is for programming questions. You should probably ask this question on Server Fault.

Answer (score 0):

It was selinux config I had to change under /etc/selinux/config

changed `enforcing` to `disable`